# Passing two arguments of differing types

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function, let's call it altHead, that takes 2 variables and outputs a variable such that:

```
a -> [a] -> a
```

I want to call it like this:

```
altHead 3 [1,2,3,4]
```

What it should do is to look at the first variable, and the list. If the list is empty, then return the first var's value; otherwise, return the list.

In this case, I've written the following code.

```
altHead :: a -> [a] -> a
altHead (x:xs) = if null[xs] then [x] else [xs]
```

However, I believe x:xs only looks through the list.

I'm a bit stuck as to how to change this so that it looks at the first value as well, and how to include the first value in the function.

Comment: Hint: don't use if/then/else at all.  Pattern matching is all you need.

Comment: @Carl Hmmm so, altHead [] = x //// altHead [a] = [a] ?

Comment: `(x:xs)` doesn't bind two arguments, it binds the head and tail of a *single* argument that must be a list.

Comment: @Wyzard Aye, this is the conclusion I came to as well. Just wasn't sure how to include the first var in there too...

Comment: `altHead a (x:xs) =`

Comment: @Wyzard ok, let me try this and see if it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like:

```
altHead :: a -> [a] -> a
altHead a xs = if null xs then a else head xs
```

Or alternatively, using pattern matching on the list:

```
altHead :: a -> [a] -> a
altHead a [] = a
altHead a (x:xs) = x
```

Comment: The last line of the second example can also be written `altHead _ (x:_) = x`, since neither `a` nor `xs` are actually used.

Comment: Yes, I just thought it helped readability/understanding to leave them as variable names.  (It also shows the `(x:xs)` pattern that the OP used.)

Comment: I think I now understand something I had fundamentally MISunderstood previously. Thanks for this, saw it just as I had finished my version, and it was a little bit off, but otherwise ok. Quick Q: I realise this isn't how typing would work normally, but is it possible for it to return the entire LIST if it's not empty, but otherwise only return x?

Comment: You can't have a function that sometimes returns a list and sometimes returns a single value, because those are different types.  But you could change the signature to `a -> [a] -> [a]` and return `[a]` when the list is empty.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. Gonna learn me some more Haskell, cheers guys!

Comment: Doesn't `altHead a (x:xs) = x` return `x` even when `xs` is not `null`?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, however, the input list is not `null`, because it's not just `xs`, but `(x:xs)`.  If `xs == []` (the definition of `null`), then it would be `x:[] == [x]`.  When the input list is `null`, that's taken care of by the line `altHead a [] = a`.